# How to export calendar from a nextcloud instance?

Tags: api, nextcloud

I have some data on a nextcloud instance I don't administrate and I want to retrieve all calendar events I put on it. The [documentation](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/nextcloud-deck-delivers-file-attachments-checkboxes-and-export/34051/8) assume you have access to more than the web interface as a user (which is not my case)

Is there an REST API to export calendar data (preferably in JSON)? If not, is there any other mean to retrieve it via the web interface?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the calender as [`.ics` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar).

The link is:

```
https://[www.example.org]/remote.php/dav/calendars/[user]/[calendername]?export
```

Replace everything in brackets. You will need to pass the credentials.

---

The web interface offers that Download link in the menu next to the calender name:

[image: download calendar from gui]